# SQL server procedure call with Spring boot jpa error: "Unable to extract OUT/INOUT parameter value"

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

We are trying to call a SQL server procedure call (3 parameters):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [mvm].[CHECK_USER]
   @IN_USER char(40),
   @IN_PASS char(40),
   @OUT_OK  int output
AS
BEGIN TRY ...
...
SET @OUT_OK = 0
...
RETURN @OUT_OK (Yes! It has a return)
```

In the Java Spring Boot app we add these to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And we made two aproaches in repository:

Aproach 1 (Annotations):

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "CheckUser",
        procedureName = "mvm.CHECK_USER",
        parameters = {
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, /*name = "@IN_USER",*/ type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, /*name = "@IN_PASS",*/ type = String.class),
          @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.INOUT /*name = "@OUT_OK",*/, type = Long.class  )
        })
})
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id //To avoid build fail
    private int id; 
}
```

And then:

```
public interface TableCheckUser extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Procedure(name = "CheckUser")
    Long checkUser(String user, String password, Long value);

}
```

In this case we have the error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Could not locate parameter registered using that position [4]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate parameter registered using that position [4]
```

Aproach 2 (Writed):

```
@Repository
public class ProcedureInvoker {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public ProcedureInvoker(final EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
public long getCheckUserValue(String user, String password) {

        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("mvm.CHECK_USER");


        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Long.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);


        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1, user);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2, password);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(3, new Long(3));

        storedProcedureQuery.execute();

//Another try (with fail) Call to stored procedure [mvm.checkUser] returned no results
        //Object myobj = storedProcedureQuery.getSingleResult();
        //final Long otherlong = (Long) myobj;

        final Long outputValue2 = (Long) storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(3);

        return outputValue2; 
    }
```

And we get:

```
2018-09-28 09:36:15.697 TRACE -- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder                    : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [myuser]
2018-09-28 09:36:15.770 TRACE --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder                    : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [mypass]
2018-09-28 09:36:15.844 TRACE --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder                    : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [3]
2018-09-28 09:36:15.977 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.r.i.OutputsImpl                      : Building Return [isResultSet=false, updateCount=-1, extendedReturn=false
2018-09-28 09:36:17.323 DEBUG --- [l-1 housekeeper] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                       : HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)
2018-09-28 09:36:22.940 DEBUG --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Unable to extract OUT/INOUT parameter value [n/a]
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.checkClosed(SQLServerStatement.java:1014)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement.getLong(SQLServerCallableStatement.java:651)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.getLong(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
```

We tried several aproaches (add parameter, remove output parameter), but with error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved!!

I didn´t need execute() line.
It works only with this:

```
   StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("mvm.CHECK_USER");


        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, Long.class, ParameterMode.INOUT);


        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(1, user);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(2, password);
        storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(3, new Long(3));

        Long outputValue2 = (Long) storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was banging my head for 4 hours

Answer (score 1):

Approach1 working for me

```
create or replace PROCEDURE test222(x IN   VARCHAR2, y IN   VARCHAR2, z OUT   VARCHAR2
)
AS             
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line ('Welcome ');
insert into person values (x,y);
z := x;
END test222;
```

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "test222", procedureName = "test222",
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "x", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "y", type = String.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "z", type = String.class)
                }
        )
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "Test")
public class Test implements Serializable
```

```
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, Long> {


    @Procedure
    String test222(String x, String y);
}
```